# Python BeautifulSoup extract text between element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to extract "THIS IS MY TEXT" from the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
   <td class="MYCLASS">
      <!-- a comment -->
      <a hef="xy">Text</a>
      <p>something</p>
      THIS IS MY TEXT
      <p>something else</p>
      </br>
   </td>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried it this way:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for hit in soup.findAll(attrs={'class' : 'MYCLASS'}):
    print hit.text
```

But I get all the text between all nested Tags plus the comment.

Can anyone help me to just get "THIS IS MY TEXT" out of this?

Comment: I was looking for this too, in order to get strings of posts that I wanted to use elsewhere. I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beautifulsoup/-VQdp2p0I8E) to be quite simple: If the soup is disposable, one could use `soup.html.unwrap()` and `soup.body.unwrap()` which will remove the tags, such that `print(soup)` would give everything but those tags.

Answer (score 56):

Learn more about how to navigate [through the parse tree in `BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#contents). Parse tree has got `tags` and `NavigableStrings` (as THIS IS A TEXT). An example

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 
doc = ['<html><head><title>Page title</title></head>',
       '<body><p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.',
       '<p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.',
       '</html>']
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc))

print soup.prettify()
# <html>
#  <head>
#   <title>
#    Page title
#   </title>
#  </head>
#  <body>
#   <p id="firstpara" align="center">
#    This is paragraph
#    <b>
#     one
#    </b>
#    .
#   </p>
#   <p id="secondpara" align="blah">
#    This is paragraph
#    <b>
#     two
#    </b>
#    .
#   </p>
#  </body>
# </html>
```

To move down the parse tree you have `contents` and `string`.

- > contents is an ordered list of the Tag and NavigableString objects
  >   contained within a page element
- > if a tag has only one child node, and that child node is a string,
  >   the child node is made available as tag.string, as well as
  >   tag.contents[0]

For the above, that is to say you can get

```
soup.b.string
# u'one'
soup.b.contents[0]
# u'one'
```

For several children nodes, you can have for instance

```
pTag = soup.p
pTag.contents
# [u'This is paragraph ', <b>one</b>, u'.']
```

***so here you may play with `contents` and get contents at the index you want.***

You also can iterate over a Tag, this is a shortcut. For instance,

```
for i in soup.body:
    print i
# <p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.</p>
# <p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.</p>
```

Comment: `hit.string` is `None` and `hit.contents[0]` is `u'\n'`, so please provide an answer for the example from the question.

Comment: so here you may play with contents and get contents at the index you want.

Comment: is the answer to the question

Answer (score 19):

Use [`.children`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) instead:

```
from bs4 import NavigableString, Comment
print ''.join(unicode(child) for child in hit.children 
    if isinstance(child, NavigableString) and not isinstance(child, Comment))
```

Yes, this is a bit of a dance.

Output:

```
>>> for hit in soup.findAll(attrs={'class' : 'MYCLASS'}):
...     print ''.join(unicode(child) for child in hit.children 
...         if isinstance(child, NavigableString) and not isinstance(child, Comment))
... 




      THIS IS MY TEXT
```

Comment: That would return `u'\n a comment \nText\nsomething\n      THIS IS MY TEXT\n      something else\n'` or `u'a commentTextsomethingTHIS IS MY TEXTsomething else'` which have more text than required.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: Of course, you are correct, not paying attention here. Updating.

Comment: This is the only solution that does not depend upon the text being in sequence or positional relationship to a specific other, but rather pulls all the text from the specified tag/element while ignoring text (or other contents) of child tags/elements. Thanks! It is awkward, but it works and solves my problem (I'm not the OP, but had a similar need).

Answer (score 18):

You can use [`.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children):

```
>>> for hit in soup.findAll(attrs={'class' : 'MYCLASS'}):
...     print hit.contents[6].strip()
... 
THIS IS MY TEXT
```

Comment: Thanks, but the text is not always at the same place. Will it work anyway?

Comment: @ɥɔǝnqɹǝƃloɥ Alas not. Perhaps use other people's answers

Comment: What does the number `6` signify?

Comment: @User Since `.contents` returns a list, we are getting the 7th element from the list (i.e the 6th index), which is the text

Answer (score 12):

with your own soup object:

```
soup.p.next_sibling.strip()
```

1. you grab the <p> directly with `soup.p` *(this hinges on it being the first <p> in the parse tree)
2. then use `next_sibling` on the tag object that `soup.p` returns since the desired text is nested at the same level of the parse tree as the <p>
3. `.strip()` is just a Python str method to remove leading and trailing whitespace

*otherwise just [find](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) the element using your choice of [filter](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters)(s)

in the interpreter this looks something like:

```
In [4]: soup.p
Out[4]: <p>something</p>

In [5]: type(soup.p)
Out[5]: bs4.element.Tag

In [6]: soup.p.next_sibling
Out[6]: u'\n      THIS IS MY TEXT\n      '

In [7]: type(soup.p.next_sibling)
Out[7]: bs4.element.NavigableString

In [8]: soup.p.next_sibling.strip()
Out[8]: u'THIS IS MY TEXT'

In [9]: type(soup.p.next_sibling.strip())
Out[9]: unicode
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more explanatory text about how this answers this question?

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: `soup.findAll('p')[0].next`

Real answer: You need an invariant reference point from which you can get to your target.

You mention in your comment to Haidro's answer that the text you want is not always in the same place. Find a sense in which it is in the same place relative to some element. Then figure out how to make BeautifulSoup navigate the parse tree following that invariant path.

For example, in the HTML you provide in the original post, the target string appears immediately after the first paragraph element, and that paragraph is not empty. Since `findAll('p')` will find paragraph elements, `soup.find('p')[0]` will be the first paragraph element.

You could in this case use `soup.find('p')` but `soup.findAll('p')[n]` is more general since maybe your actual scenario needs the 5th paragraph or something like that.

The `next` field attribute will be the next parsed element in the tree, including children. So `soup.findAll('p')[0].next` contains the text of the paragraph, and `soup.findAll('p')[0].next.next` will return your target in the HTML provided.

Answer (score 4):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for hit in soup.findAll(attrs={'class' : 'MYCLASS'}):
  hit = hit.text.strip()
  print hit
```

This will print: THIS IS MY TEXT
Try this..

Answer (score 0):

The [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) provides an example about removing objects from a document using the extract method. In the following example the aim is to remove all comments from the document:

**Removing Elements**

> Once you have a reference to an element, you can rip it out of the
>   tree with the extract method. This code *removes all the comments*
>   from a document:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, Comment
soup = BeautifulSoup("""1<!--The loneliest number-->
                    <a>2<!--Can be as bad as one--><b>3""")
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
[comment.extract() for comment in comments]
print soup
# 1
# <a>2<b>3</b></a>
```