# How to select only this text node using BeautifulSoup and Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

I have this html stucture :

```
<div class="foo">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <br>Some text I want to retrieve. <br><br> This text too.
    <br> (numbers and position of "br" tag indetermined) And this one too.
    <div class="subfoo">Some other text I don't want.</div>
</div>
```

In my python script, I have written :

```
exampleSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
elems = exampleSoup.select('.foo')
print(elems[0].getText())
```

As expected I get the whole text :

```
Title
Some text I want to retrieve.
Some other text I don't want.
```

How to get only the string in the div that has no tag around ie :*"Some text I want to retrieve. This text too. And this one too."* ?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python BeautifulSoup extract text between element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`.next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling)
 to get the next element in the tree.

**Example**

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> print soup.prettify()
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="foo">
   <h3>
    Title
   </h3>
   Some text I want to retrieve.
   <div class="subfoo">
    Some other text I don't want.
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

>>> print soup.find('div', { 'class' : 'foo' } ).h3.next_sibling.strip()
Some text I want to retrieve.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It returns me `<br>`. Indeed, sorry but I have forgot to mention that along with the text there is some <br> placed randomly.  I've updated my question.