# Retrieve the text value from element in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve the price from the URl mentioned in the code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.forever21.com/IN/Product/Product.aspx?
 BR=LOVE21&Category=whatsnew_app&ProductID=2000054242&VariantID=")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
#print(soup.prettify())
price = soup.find_all("font",{"class":"items_price"})
print(price)

#Output:
<font class="items_price">Rs.1,249</font>
```

I need just the price which is Rs.1,249
Can someone say what needs to be done?
Thank you

Comment: You just need  `soup.find("font",{"class":"items_price"}).text`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python BeautifulSoup extract text between element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ResultSet is a list.

```
print (price[0].get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply user [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

```
>>> price = soup.find("font",{"class":"items_price"})
>>> print(price.get_text())
'Rs.1,249'
```

Comment: Tried, got an error : AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: @KeshavReddy - Since, you've used `find_all` this returns multiple elements, hence it returns a `ResultSet`. You can use `price[0].get_text()` or you can simply use [`find`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) to fetch only a single element.