# Python how to extract contents from html file

Tags: python-2.7

I have a Test Report file from Nose in html format. 
I would like to extract some parts of the text out of it in Python.  I will be sending this in an email in the message part.

I have the following sample:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Unit Test Report</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

<style>
body {
    font-family: Calibri, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
}
* {
    word-break: break-all;
}
table, td, th, .dataid {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: #fff;
}
section {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    margin: 2ex;
    padding: 1ex;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 130%;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 120%;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 100%;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 85%;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, a[href] {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #0074d9;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h3 strong, a.failed {
    color: #ff4136;
}
.failed {
    color: #ff4136;
}
a.success {
    color: #3d9970;
}
pre {
    font-family: 'Consolas', 'Deja Vu Sans Mono',
                 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono', 'Monaco',
                 'Courier New', monospace;
}

.test-details,
.traceback {
    display: none;
}
section:target .test-details {
    display: block;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Overview</h1>
    <section>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Class</th>
                <th class="failed">Fail</th>
                <th class="failed">Error</th>
                <th>Skip</th>
                <th>Success</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Regression_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase2.RegressionProject_TestCase2</td>
                    <td class="failed">1</td>
                    <td class="failed">9</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>219</td>
                    <td>229</td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                <td class="failed">1</td>
                <td class="failed">9</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>219</td>
                <td>229</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
    <h1>Failure details</h1>
            <section>
                <h2>Regression_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase2.RegressionProject_TestCase2 (1 failures, 9 errors)</h2>
                <div>
                        <section id="Regression_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase2.RegressionProject_TestCase2:test_00010_import_user_invalid_credentials">
                            <h3>test_00010_import_user_invalid_credentials: <strong>selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException</strong></h3>
                            <div class="test-details">
                                <h4>Traceback</h4>
                                <pre class="traceback">Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\unittest\case.py", line 329, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\ClearCore - Regression Test\Regression_TestCase\RegressionProject_TestCase2.py", line 221, in test_00010_import_user_invalid_credentials
    Globals.login_password_invalid)
  File "C:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\ClearCore - Regression Test\Pages\security.py", line 51, in enter_invalid_userid_and_password
    self.enter_user_id(userid)
  File "C:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\ClearCore - Regression Test\Pages\security.py", line 32, in enter_user_id
    user_id_element = self.get_element(*MainPageLocators.security_user_id_textfield_xpath)
  File "C:\test_runners\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\ClearCore - Regression Test\Pages\base.py", line 40, in get_element
    element = self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 712, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: Message: Unable to find element with xpath == //span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel marginbelow myinlineblock" and contains(text(), "User ID (including domain)")]/following-sibling::input

-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------
*** Test import_invalid_user_credentials ***
05_12_1616_49_42
//span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel marginbelow myinlineblock" and contains(text(), "User ID (including domain)")]/following-sibling::input
Element not found 
Message: Unable to find element with xpath == //span[@class="gwt-InlineLabel marginbelow myinlineblock" and contains(text(), "User ID (including domain)")]/following-sibling::input

05_12_1616_51_54

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------
----
 # There is more html below. I have not included everything. It will be too long otherwise.
```

If i open the file in the browser the formatting looks like this:
This is the text I would like to extract from the html file.

```
    Class             Fail Error    Skip    Success     Total
Regression_TestCase     1    9       0      219         229
```

How can i do this please?  It would be nice to keep it in a  table format.
Thanks, Riaz

Comment: Have you tried anything with an xml parsing library? (like https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree )

Comment: I was looking up Beautiful Soup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element

Comment: What format do you want the output to be in? Do you want it to look like a table in excel (e.g. csv) or do you want a text file with those rows and columns and spacings?

Answer (score 1):

Your sample html code contains unclosed tags and closing tags without opening tags. I'll assume you are only showing a sample and that that the file you extract will well-formed as below:

```
<body>
    <h1>Overview</h1>
    <section>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Class</th>
                <th class="failed">Fail</th>
                <th class="failed">Error</th>
                <th>Skip</th>
                <th>Success</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Regression_TestCase</td>
                    <td class="failed">1</td>
                    <td class="failed">9</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>219</td>
                    <td>229</td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
                <td class="failed">1</td>
                <td class="failed">9</td>
                <td>0</td>
                <td>219</td>
                <td>229</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     </section>
</body>
```

You can use the Etree module to parse the code as xml. **EDIT:** Changed the method used to find the table to using xpath and made it so that the "Total" column will not be printed.

**EDIT 2:** I have now used regular expressions to extract all tables in the code. Be careful using this as it is a very fragile solution. If there is an open table tag without a closing table tag, then it will extract all text after the open table tag and crash because the resulting string will not be well-formed xml.

```
import csv
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Extract well formed tables
start = re.compile(r"<table>", re.IGNORECASE)
end = re.compile(r"</table>", re.IGNORECASE)
html_code = ""
table = False
with open('sample2.xml') as xmlfile:
    for line in xmlfile:
        if not table:
            table = start.search(line)
            if table:
                html_code += line
        else:
            if end.search(line):
                html_code += line[0:end.search(line).end()]
                table = False
            else:
                html_code += line
                table = not end.search(line)            
print html_code

# Parse html code into Etree Element object
root = ET.fromstring(html_code)
elements = root.findall(".//tr")
print elements
row = []
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for tablerow in elements:
        # Only write result to file if there is text inside the first column
        if list(tablerow)[0].text:
            for col in list(tablerow):
                row.append(col.text)
            csvwriter.writerow(row)
            print row
            row = []
```

If you open "output.csv" using excel, you will have your table. If you are using this method, please note the security warnings in the documentation (link in zezollo's comment).

Alternatively, you can use regular expressions but I am too tired to write up another solution. Perhaps tomorrow, or someone else might be kind enough to provide an alternate solution.

Comment: When i parse my html file I am getting the error xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 125, column 47

Comment: The code to parse html file is: tree = ET.parse(r"E:\SeleniumTestReport.html")

Comment: Do all the opening tags in your html code have closing tags (and vice versa)? As for your second comment, my code assumes that the html file is in the same directory as the python script. If you have put your html file in a different directory, then naturally the path you use to parse it needs to be different.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, my method assumes well-formed, complete html code. The file you have given is not complete. I can use regular expressions to extract a well-formed xml out of your code, but with no table id, I'm hesitant to do so because it would be a very fragile solution for what is already a very fragile system. Is there a possibility that your program will return code with more than one table?

Comment: I've updated the code. If I use your entire sample code (including all the errors and any other random text, it will extract what you are after. However, note that it will break if there is html code anywhere with an open <table> tag that isn't paired with a closing </table> tag.