# Grabbing only a certain section of an html element

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to webscraping and looking for a more pythonic way to grab only a certain subsection of an element. In this case, I only need the postal code of an address.

I created a clunky solution and I feel that there must be a better way than what I'm doing here.

```
     In [79]: address
     Out[79]: ['columbus, In, United States']

     In [80]: address[0].split(',')[1][1:]
     Out[80]: 'In'
     #and if that wasn't long enough
     In [82]: address[0].split(',')[1][1:].upper() 
     Out[82]: 'IN'
```

Comment: Have you tried (or are you currently using) [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) makes doing something like that really easy. Here's some examples [Python BeautifulSoup extract text between element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element), and [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: @downshift I'm using `lxml.html` , if BeautifulSoup is what I need to do this, than I'd rather just go wtih my method since this is to simple of a script to need such a large package. I'm just looking for a more pythonic way to parse the string.

Comment: no you don't need BeautifulSoup or any big package like that, I'm sure it can be done pythonically with python's built-in modules or  `lxml.html` something like that, but I don't know if they can be done in a better manner or any less clunky

Comment: You've grabbed the state/province abbreviation, not the postal code (ZIP code in the US).  Is this just a terminology error?

Comment: Frankly, you've done pretty well at extracting what you want.  **strip** might be a little safer than **[1:]**, in case there's extra white space.  However ugly the code might appear, the operations are quick enough, and you're getting the desired result.  You have a clunky solution because, in terms of information flow, it's a clunky problem.

Comment: @Prune thanks for confirming this with me. I'm just figuring new things out and wanted to know if there was more efficient ways. As for the postal code, I believe that is just a broad definition as [here](https://www.infoplease.com/state-abbreviations-and-state-postal-codes) it is used differently.

Comment: Thanks for the "postal code" link; in UK & Canada "postal code" what we'd call the ZIP code here in USer land.