# Extract <tr> tag data without class or Id

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract date from following html using Beautiful Soup

```
 <tr class="TTRow">
        <td>
        <a class="tablebluelink" href="" target="_blank">517330</a></td>
        <td class="TTRow_left">CMI</td>
        <td>29 Jun 2017</td>
    </tr>
```

I thought this would work

```
r=urllib.urlopen('http://www.bseindia.com/corporates/Forth_Results.aspx?expandable=0').read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(r)
companies= soup.findAll("tr", class_= "TTRow")
i=0
for company in companies:
    upcoming_company_results[i]=str(company.find("td",class_="TTRow_left").text)
    date[i]=str(company.find("td").text)
    i=i+1
```

But it gives the text with class="tablbluelink" for date[i] instead of dates.
How to extract the Date "29 Jun 2017" form it.

Comment: I found a solution and made use of Contents, if you are stuck somewhere like this refer, https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#contents

Answer (score 0):

I made use of contents, use this answer for better reference [Python BeautifulSoup extract text between element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element)

```
for company in companies:
    upcoming_company_results[i]=str(company.find("td",class_="TTRow_left").text)
    date[i]= str(company.contents[3].text)
    i=i+1
```