# How can I extract this text using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use beautifulsoup to scrape reviews from beeradvocate.  The code for a review looks like this:

```
[<span class="BAscore_norm">4.49</span>,
 <span class="rAvg_norm">/5</span>,
 u'\xa0\xa0rDev ',
 <span style="color:#006600;">+2%</span>,
 <br/>,
 <span class="muted">look: 4.25 | smell: 4.5 | taste: 4.5 | feel: 4.5 |  
 overall: 4.5</span>,
 <br/>,
 <br/>,
 u'Pours a slightly hazy golden orange with two fingers white head. ',
 <br/>,
 u'\nSmells of citrus, orange, pineapple, sweet malty presence.',
 <br/>,
 u'\nTastes starts with the juicy orange, pineapple. Finishes with a 
 somewhat sweet caramel toffee like malt presence.',
 <br/>,
 u'\nVery smooth medium body. Alchohol was very well hidden until it started 
 to warm a bit.',
 <br/>,
 u'\nOverall a really tasty brew!',
 <br/>,
 <br/>,
 <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i>,
 u'\xa0',
 <span class="muted">354 characters</span>,
 <br/>,
 <br/>,
 <div><span class="muted"><a class="username" 
href="/community/members/jbowengeorgia.1171914/">JBowenGeorgia</a>, <a 
href="/beer/profile/26/1558/?ba=JBowenGeorgia#review">Oct 03, 2017</a>
</span></div>]
```

I'm lost as to how to extract the text of the review. There's a similar question at [Python BeautifulSoup extract text between element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element) but most of the answers involve .contents and positional argument which won't work here because of the line breaks between paragraphs in the reviews.

Comment: It would be great to have the initial html code, not only the print from python.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner:

```
text = ''.join(x for x in soup if type(x) == bs4.NavigableString and not x.startswith(u'\xa0'))
```

Here `soup` corresponds to the tag `<div id="rating_fullview_content_2">`. I don't know if you have this variable, but `soup.content` matches the code block you gave in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put the initial html code of the page into `html` variable:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import bs4

if __name__=="__main__":
    with open('page.html') as page:
        html = page.read()
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

        reviews = soup.br.find_next_siblings(text=True)
        reviews = map(lambda x: x.strip(), reviews)  # remove whitespace
        reviews = filter(lambda x: bool(x), reviews)  # remove empty strings

        for review in reviews:
            print "REVIEW:", review
```

This will give you something like:

```
REVIEW: Pours a slightly hazy golden orange with two fingers white head.
REVIEW: Smells of citrus, orange, pineapple, sweet malty presence.
REVIEW: Tastes starts with the juicy orange, pineapple. Finishes with a
 somewhat sweet caramel toffee like malt presence.
REVIEW: Very smooth medium body. Alchohol was very well hidden until it started
to warm a bit.
REVIEW: Overall a really tasty brew!
REVIEW: \xa0
```