# Getting text into div with python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm learning python and the lib beatifulsoup to do some crawlers and i want to extract a text from a html code but the text is not into a tag. look the code

My bs4 code is this:

```
for p in soup.find_all("div", class_="description__container-text"):
    v1 = p
    for x in v1:
        print(v1)
```

and the output is this:

```
<div class="description__container-text" itemprop="description"> 
    <h2 class="description__product-title">
        TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT” HD
    </h2> 
    <p class="description__text"></p> 
    *********I WANT TO EXTRACT THIS TEXT HEAR!!!!!!*************************************************** 
    <p class="description__text"></p> 
    <p class="description__text"> 
        <center>
            <iframe frameborder="0" height="6500" src="https://myurl.html" width="100%"></iframe>
        </center>
```

so, how can i get the text:

```
*********I WANT TO EXTRACT THIS TEXT HEAR!!!!!!***************************************************
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python BeautifulSoup extract text between element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you want to specify the item you want. I am going to assume that you want to specify the text you want as that which follows the `p` element with `class` 'description_text'. But the method I'm describing works more generally.

First find an element that encloses the one you want to find. In this case, I've chosen the `div`. Then browse through that element's descendants until you see the one that immediately precedes the one you want.

For illustrative purposes (and my own laziness) I haven't written this in the form of a loop. Use `items = div.descendants` to get an iterator in `items`. Then use `next` to obtain each descendant of the `div` in turn, in `item`.

If the `item.name` is empty then the `item` is a string, otherwise, `item.name` names the tag. When you see the `p` tag mentioned above you know that the next item will be the text item you actually want.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('bueno.htm').read(), 'lxml')
>>> div = soup.find('div')
>>> items = div.descendants
>>> item = next(items)
>>> item.name
>>> item
' '
>>> item = next(items)
>>> item.name
'h2'
>>> item
<h2 class="description__product-title">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT” HD</h2>
>>> item = next(items)
>>> item.name
>>> item
'TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT” HD'
>>> item = next(items)
>>> item.name
>>> item
' '
>>> item = next(items)
>>> item.name
'p'
>>> item
<p class="description__text"></p>
>>> item = next(items)
>>> item.name
>>> item
' *********I WANT TO EXTRACT THIS TEXT HEAR!!!!!!*************************************************** \n    '
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, this work fine for this page, i just dont have sure if the HTML structure will be the same for other pages, to do a crawler for many "equal" pages. Anyway, Thank You

Comment: You're welcome, Thiago. That's the big problem with parsing HTML. Very often the techniques apply only to certain situations. If you like, post another question with one of those pages and then put a comment to me here. I'd be glad to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to grab all the text from that div element and than subtract the other text you don't want using `str.replace()`

Here's an example that removes the `h2` text and trims the end result to get rid of white space

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


doc = """
<div class="description__container-text" itemprop="description"> <h2                          class="description__product-title">TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT” HD</h2>
 <p class="description__text"></p> *********I WANT TO EXTRACT THIS TEXT                       HEAR!!!!!!***************************************************
    <p class="description__text"></p>
 <p class="description__text"> <center><iframe frameborder="0" height="6500" src="https://    myurl.html" width="100%"></iframe></center>
</p>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
print("all text: %s" % soup.get_text())
allText = soup.get_text()
h2Text = soup.find('h2').get_text()
# separate h2 text
print("h2 text: %s" %h2Text)
# remove h2 text from all text
modifiedAllText = allText.replace(h2Text, '')
print("Modified: %s" % modifiedAllText.strip())
```