# Parsing out specific values from JSON object in BeautifulSoup

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

```
import urllib
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://mygene.info/v3/query?q=symbol:CDK2&species:human&fields=name,symbol,entrezgene'
html = request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

**Output:**

```
<html><body><p>{
  "max_score": 88.84169,
  "took": 6,
  "total": 244,
  "hits": [
    {
      "_id": "1017",
      "_score": 88.84169,
      "entrezgene": "1017",
      "name": "cyclin dependent kinase 2",
      "symbol": "CDK2"
    },
    {
      "_id": "12566",
      "_score": 73.8155,
      "entrezgene": "12566",
      "name": "cyclin-dependent kinase 2",
      "symbol": "Cdk2"
    },
    {
      "_id": "362817",
      "_score": 62.09322,
      "entrezgene": "362817",
      "name": "cyclin dependent kinase 2",
      "symbol": "Cdk2"
    }
  ]
}</p></body></html>
```

**Goal**: 
From this output, I would like to parse out the  `entrezgene`,  `name`, and `symbol` values

**Question**:
How do I go about accomplishing this?

**Background:**
I have tried https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class and [Python BeautifulSoup extract text between element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element) to name a couple but I am not able to find what I am looking for

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can get the `text` which is in *[json](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)* format. Then use *[json.loads()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/json.html#json.loads)* to convert it to a *Dictionary*.

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
url = 'http://mygene.info/v3/query?q=symbol:CDK2&species:human&fields=name,symbol,entrezgene'
html = request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
site_json=json.loads(soup.text)
#printing for entrezgene, do the same for name and symbol
print([d.get('entrezgene') for d in site_json['hits'] if d.get('entrezgene')])
```

Output:

```
['1017', '12566', '362817', '100117828', '109992509', '100981695', '100925631']
```

Comment: change the code like : 
   site_json=json.loads(soup.string) 
and it worked!