# Web scraping into list

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to add the following tags to a list that should look like this. `[Computer Science 1026A/B,Computer Science 2120A/B,Engineering Science 1036A/B, Digital Humatities 2220A/B]`

I have tried everything I can think of. The problem is that this `<div>` class has no name as it seems

```html
<div><strong>Antirequisite(s):</strong> <a
        href="Courses.cfm?CourseAcadCalendarID=MAIN_006440_1&amp;SelectedCalendar=Live&amp;ArchiveID=">Computer Science
    1026A/B,</a> <a href="Courses.cfm?CourseAcadCalendarID=MAIN_023958_1&amp;SelectedCalendar=Live&amp;ArchiveID=">Computer
    Science 2120A/B,</a> <a
        href="Courses.cfm?CourseAcadCalendarID=MAIN_019426_1&amp;SelectedCalendar=Live&amp;ArchiveID=">Engineering
    Science 1036A/B,</a> Digital Humatities 2220A/B.
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Post the code that produces teh problem you're having.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python BeautifulSoup extract text between element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element)

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `//strong[contains(text(),"Antirequisite")]/following-sibling::a/text()` to loop through all the elements containing 'Antirequisite' text and get the text.