# extract text from two tables by Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a lot of pages where the structure is the following:

```html
<table class='CERTAIN_CLASS'> ... </table>

A lot of stuff here (divs, ps, brs, images)

<table class='CERTAIN_CLASS'> ... </table>
```

What is the most efficient way to extract the text (*text only!*) from everything between two tables of a certain class? I've found a lot of similar questions on SO, but nothing on this secifically  this task.

Comment: Does this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already loaded the content of the html page:

For a specific class:

```
text.find(class_="CERTAIN CLASS").text.strip()
```

To find all the text from this certain class, then you could iterate through every element:

```
text.findAll(class_="CERTAIN CLASS"):
```