# Python (Beautiful Soup) to Pull out Text?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, translation

I'd like to pull some text from between two tags from multiple html files and then add that text to separate files.

The basic idea is that I need to translate different parts of the page into different languages.

This text will go to be translated, come back and then need to be added back to where it originally was in the html files.

I'm pretty sure I should use Beautiful Soup to do this, but I have no idea how. I've looked at other questions on this site but there are a few specifics to mine that have made this difficult.

1. The tags aren't html tags, they are xml but also have spaces

So for example it's something like

```
<Generic:tagName more-st-uff="Foo_Bar.xx_YY">text to be translated</Generic:tagName>

<Generic:tagName more-st-uff="Foo_Bar.aa_BB">text to be translated</Generic:tagName>
```

In this case xx_YY and aa_BB are language tags, language abbreviation_COUNTRY ABBREVIATION

2. I'd like this to run on multiple files simultaneously
3. Each text snippet should go in it's own file
4. I need to get that text snipped (translated) back into the html files somehow.

Where do I even begin? I'm fairly new to Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python BeautifulSoup extract text between element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element)

Answer (score 0):

1. BeautifulSoup works fine with XML.
2. You can use [os.listdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to get the XML files, then loop over them and process each one.
3. You could have a running tag counter and produce a filename with the tag number in it.
4. You can write attributes (e.g. set `attr` or `text`) in BeautifulSoup, then use `str(soup)` on the document to get back the modified XHTML.

Since this is for a translation job, I assume that you will want to write two Python scripts that are very similar. Based on a directory of XML files, the first script could extract all the text you need to translate into numbered files. The second script would do the exact same iteration over tags, but read text from numbered files and write them to tags instead. It would then write the modified XHTML to a new file.