# How to remove HTML tags of a result from Beatifulsoup find all

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to remove the tags and leave only the text in the below codes output using python and beautifulsoup.

Output :
[image]

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
r = requests.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp")
soup = bs(r.content)
print(soup.prettify())


first_header = soup.find(["h2", "h2"])

first_headers = soup.find_all(["h2", "h2"])
first_headers
```

Comment: does `first_headers.text` work?

Comment: first_headers.text works as shown in the output

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936466/beautifulsoup-grab-visible-webpage-text) answer your question?

Comment: Confusion to combine code from the link

Comment: did you try this `first_headers = soup.findAll(["h2", "h2"], text=True)`? Firstly edit your ques and add `html` and `web scraping` tags.

Comment: You can also checkout [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element)

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: Results like this - Tutorials
References
Exercises and Quizzes,
HTML
HTML
HTML
HTML
HTML
HTML
HTML
What is HTML?
A Simple HTML Document
What is an HTML Element?
Web Browsers
HTML Page Structure
HTML History
Report Error
Thank You For Helping Us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
r = requests.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp")
soup = bs(r.content,features="html.parser") # getting content from webpage
# retriving all h1 and h2 tags and extracting text from each of them 
first_headers = [html.text for html in soup.find_all(["h1", "h2"])] 
print(first_headers)
```

I used list comprehension to solve it in a single line you can use a for loop instead which goes as

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
r = requests.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp")
soup = bs(r.content,features="html.parser")

first_headers = soup.find_all(["h1", "h2"])
for i in first_headers:
    print(i.text)
```

This is the output of my code:

```
Tutorials
References
Exercises and Quizzes
HTML Tutorial
HTML Forms
HTML Graphics
HTML Media
HTML APIs
HTML Examples
HTML References
HTML Introduction
What is HTML?
A Simple HTML Document
What is an HTML Element?
Web Browsers
HTML Page Structure
HTML History
Report Error
Thank You For Helping Us!
```

Answer (score 0):

To get only the text from your `ResultSet` iterate over it e.g. with `list comprehension`, call `.text` for every element and `.join()` all text elements by `whitespace`:

```
' '.join([e.text for e in soup.find_all('h2')])
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
r = requests.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp")
soup = bs(r.content)


first_headers = ' '.join([e.text for e in soup.find_all('h2')])

print(first_headers)
```

#### Output

```
Tutorials References Exercises and Quizzes HTML Tutorial HTML Forms HTML Graphics HTML Media HTML APIs HTML Examples HTML References What is HTML? A Simple HTML Document What is an HTML Element? Web Browsers HTML Page Structure HTML History Report Error Thank You For Helping Us!
```