# how to get text between two SETS of tags in python

Tags: python, html, url, beautifulsoup, tags

I am trying to get text between  tag and also text between sets of  tags, I have tried but I haven't got what I want. Can anyone help? I really appreciate it.

```
text = '''
 <b>Doc Type: </b>AABB
<br />
<b>Doc No: </b>BBBBF
<br />
<b>System No: </b>aaa bbb
<br />
<b>VCode: </b>040000033
<br />
<b>G Code: </b>000045
<br />  
'''
```

the expected output:

```
Doc Type: AABB
Doc No:   BBBBF
System No: aaa bbb
VCode: 040000033
G Code: 000045
```

the code I have tried, this only gave me the text between  tags, but not text outside  tags:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.find_all('b'))
```

I also tried following, but it gave me all text on the page, I only want  tags and text outside of the  tags, :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
lines = ''.join(soup.text)
print(lines)
```

the current output is:

```
Doc Type: 
Doc No:   
System No: 
VCode: 
G Code:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python BeautifulSoup extract text between element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835449/python-beautifulsoup-extract-text-between-element)

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. I tried (soup.b.next.next.strip()), it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu could use the `.next_sibling` from each of those elements.

**Code:**

```
html = '''
 <b>Doc Type: </b>AABB
<br />
<b>Doc No: </b>BBBBF
<br />
<b>System No: </b>aaa bbb
<br />
<b>VCode: </b>040000033
<br />
<b>G Code: </b>000045
<br />'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
bs = soup.find_all('b')


for each in bs:
    eachFollowingText = each.next_sibling.strip()
    print(f'{each.text} {eachFollowingText}')
```

**Output:**

```
Doc Type:  AABB
Doc No:  BBBBF
System No:  aaa bbb
VCode:  040000033
G Code:  000045
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '''
 <b>Doc Type: </b>AABB
<br />
<b>Doc No: </b>BBBBF
<br />
<b>System No: </b>aaa bbb
<br />
<b>VCode: </b>040000033
<br />
<b>G Code: </b>000045
<br />  
'''

result = [
    i.getText(strip=True) for i in 
    BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser").find_all(text=True)
    if i.getText(strip=True)
]
print("\n".join([" ".join(result[i:i + 2]) for i in range(0, len(result), 2)]))
```

Output:

```
Doc Type: AABB
Doc No: BBBBF
System No: aaa bbb
VCode: 040000033
G Code: 000045
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the full text by finding the *parent tag*, not given in the question, and then access to its string content with `.text` and some formatting operations such as removing empty lines.

`BeautifulSoup` always add an `html` tag if missing so in my example `soup.html`. A replacement with `soup.find_all(my parent tag)` should fix it assuming that you know it.

```
html = '''
 <b>Doc Type: </b>AABB
<br />
<b>Doc No: </b>BBBBF
<br />
<b>System No: </b>aaa bbb
<br />
<b>VCode: </b>040000033
<br />
<b>G Code: </b>000045
<br />
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

parent_tag = soup.html
s = '\n'.join(line for line in parent_tag.text.split('\n') if line != '')
print(s)
```